# how to set up an embedded MongoDB with a docker image

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, docker

I have the following lines of code that is intended to set up an embedded mongodb with a docker image

```
    @Container
    public static GenericContainer MONGO_CONTAINER = new GenericContainer<>("URL_OF_DOCKER")
            .withExposedPorts(27017);

    static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            final String propertyOverride = format("mongo.servers: %s:%s", MONGO_CONTAINER.getContainerIpAddress(), MONGO_CONTAINER.getMappedPort(27017));
            TestPropertyValues.of(propertyOverride).applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
        }
    }
```

However, I am unable to use the reactivemongotemplate to save documents. I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 2000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 2000 ms while waiting for a server that matches WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
```

Would anyone know the issue?

Comment: Can you access MongoDB from command line client, not from your Java code?
How do you start containerized MongoDB? Probably there is a problem with port access.

Comment: embedded mongo as docker... That is quite a contradiction. Embedded is something like the flapdoodle embedded mongoDB. You are just running a MongoDB instance in docker.

Comment: The [Testcontainers documentation](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/networking/) suggests you want to use `MONGO_CONTAINER.getHost()` and not `getContainerIpAddress`.

Comment: Just found the issue - needed TestContainer and ContextConfiguration annotations above the class